# Trying to display latitude and longitude from Google API in JS to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Want to output the latitude and longitude of the marker point in the 2 input boxes below and then also save them but that can happen later. As the user drags around the marker, the latitude and longitude should keep updating. This is the code I have already:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llF4T.png)

[JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSb9z.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtQhH.png)

Please help, I've tried to debug by adding the console.log but it isn't outputting anything which may suggest where the problem is. At least I can't see anything in Chrome dev tools. When I try to debug using Visual Studio breakpoints, none of it loads so I can't do it that way. I've tried a bunch of other stuff as well.

This is the javascript:

```
var map;
var marker = false;

function initMap() {

var centerOfMap = new google.maps.LatLng(51.487987, -0.237269); // St Paul's School

var options = {
    center: centerOfMap,
    zoom: 10
};

// extantiate a map object
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: centerOfMap,
    map: map,
    title: 'Drag me around',
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    markerLocation();
});

markerLocation();}



function markerLocation() {
        // give the information back to the HTML
        var currentLocation = marker.getPosition();
        console.log(currentLocation.lat());
        document.getElementById("lat").value = String.valueOf( currentLocation.lat());
        document.getElementById("lng").value = String.valueOf( currentLocation.lng());

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="insert-location">
    <p>Select a location where the task will be carried out. Click on a location to select it. Drag the marker to change it.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input type="text" id="lat" readonly="readonly"><br>
    <input type="text" id="lng" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you post pictures of code?

Comment: There you go @geocodezip I embedded the code

Comment: can you even see the map ? i'm trying to recreat but no luck even seeing the map

Comment: @betofarina you need your own separate key. You can get a free key from the Google Developer Platform. Google doesn't let you use their services without a unique key, and I just realised you managed to do it...

Comment: I have my own key thats I could solved the problem...i couldn't load the map because of the divs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a working example of how I solved it (add you api key):

http://jsbin.com/rinayek/1/edit?html,css,js,output

1st replace this:

```
document.getElementById("lat").value = String.valueOf( currentLocation.lat());
document.getElementById("lng").value = String.valueOf( currentLocation.lng());
```

for this:

```
document.getElementById("lat").value = currentLocation.lat();
document.getElementById("lng").value = currentLocation.lng();
```

2nd make your  `<div id="map">` that is not children of `<div class="insert-location">`

For the rest you are ok, check the example for more clarity

Comment: Thank you that worked. I added the String.valueOf afterwards, so it was definitely the extra div that was the problem.